# Flagging for Moderator Attention

Tags: discussion, flagging, new-users

Something just occurred to me as I viewed the comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31029/skorohod-topology). Akhil, a fellow moderator, wrote that

> I'll be happy to reopen if you edit the question to something more detailed and flag it for moderator attention.

However, the OP, being a completely new user, only has 1 reputation point. And a quick glance at the [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) indicates that at minimum of 15 rep is required before a user can flag a question for moderator attention.

I am inclined to suggest that, in similar situations in the future (where a question is closed for being poorly presented, but yet still has a chance to be a good question after some editing, and with the OP having fewer than 15 reputation), the comment should instead/also introduce the OP to [comment @-replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/).

(To make this a question: are there other ways for users to get a moderator's attention?)

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for pointing this out. (P.S. It would be nice if new users could flag their *own* questions.)

Comment: @AkhilMathew: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86245/flag-ones-own-question-without-reputation-limit

Comment: @Tobias: Dear Tobias, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest, if anything, to allow flagging of your own questions without a reputation limit. Just like comments and such.

(Should this answer be a comment on Willie's original question? If so, please convert it or let me know.)

Comment: Very good point - make it a feature request!

Comment: @Hendrik: I'm very lazy as it is... I just drop the ball and hope someone will pick it up and play nicely with it. :-)

Comment: Fine fine fine, [here you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86245/flag-ones-own-question-without-reputation-limit), you bum. `:-)`

Comment: @Willie: Bless your heart ;-)

Comment: I don't think I would support this. I suggest if new users need that level of assistance, they email the address at the bottom of every page.